# How to enable "Open tips" within IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Enabling "open tips" allows us to search the selected text in different sites (eg' google). I'm trying to make use of it in IntelliJ. Selecting the text and clicking on (Command + Shift + `) doesn't show any tip whereas in other applications (eg' Chrome, iTerm) shows for tip. Tried searching within keymaps if the same key is configured for something else - but it doesn't look like the case though.

[image]

Any suggestion to overcome this would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: What is the use-case for that? You can use Ctrl+J, or F1 to show quick documentation. It is better than Google when we are speaking about code.

Comment: I'm trying to use this app (https://github.com/tanin47/tip#installation) along with IntelliJ :) To use it with Jira search and across other sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of this app and using Tip with IntelliJ. It should work.

There are a couple things that you can investigate more:

- Try Tip with other applications. Does it work?
- Try activate Tip without shortcut by selecting a text, go to application menu on the top left, selecting services, and selecting "Tip: open tips" manually. Does it work?
- Try running your script manually in Terminal with a random input. Does it work?

These actions will tell you where the problem is. I hope this is helpful!